# how to best structure my linear programming using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, linear-programming

I have to solve a large number (from 2 to 10 millions) of very similar small (maybe 100 constraints) problems where only a small number of constraints, always the same change.

Essentially I want to minimize the cost of covering consumption. The rules are more or less the following:

Each customer (we have millions of them) consume a number of units of different items, this is different for each customer.
We have a number of products, each of them include one or many items, at a given cost. The products and costs are common for all customers
Further there are some additional constraints that link which products can be combined for each customer, but the constraints are again the same for all customers.
I am planning on solving this using Spark and I am not familiar with the performance of its algorithms for this problem and my question is, should I try to solve a very large number of small problems, or should I combine them in a large problem repeating the constraints between products for each customer?

Maybe grouping a few hundred thousand customers together?

Alternatively, can I somehow leverage that the individual problems are very similar to solve them faster?

Thanks

Comment: Simplex LP solvers can be very efficient in solving similar models. You probably should look at the documentation of your LP solver and search for "advanced basis", "hot(warm) start" or something like that.

Comment: Hi Erwin, thanks. We do not have a solver yet. We are still trying to understand the landscape, but I think you are correct on your assessment.

Answer (score 0):

**How Spark Generally Solves Problems**

Spark is a large scale distributed computation engine and its basic purpose is to ship the calculations to the data and solve problems in parallel leveraging in memory operations as much as possible.

Generally, you would just load all of your data into data sets or data frames (think SQL tables), and then write pseudo-SQL to solve your problem.

The customer records would just be rows in your various tables.  Spark will wait for you to specify an output step (writing to file/db/etc) and at that point it will generate an optimized query plan to execute your operations in the smartest way it knows how.

**Scaling Spark**

If its too slow or failing, you generally scale by providing spark with more cores, more memory, more executors, and by partitioning your data more intelligently (partitions are units of parallelism; spark SQL uses 200 by default).
Spark is meant to be run on a cluster of computers large enough to solve your problems all at once.  We, for example, happily process billions of rows at once without issue on an 8 node cluster.

If you don't have a real cluster or one large enough to solve your issue, you can batch your calculations which is fine; but the general approach would be similar.

**Special Libraries**

There are special libraries to handle working with graphs (GraphX), machine learning, and there are special algorithmic libraries; but it doesn't sound like you need those kinds of things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that, we have been working with Spark for quite some time. my question is how to best parallelize. One option (that i think is not a good idea) is to build a larger problem and use the algebra libraries in MLLib to take care of solving it using all the workers.But the more I think about it the more I think this is not the way. We will try to distribute different copies of the solver to the nodes and have them work on similar problems as erwin-kalvelagen suggests.